# Update highlighted cell in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I use two text fields and a button to add entries to a two column table.

If I add a new entry the table is updated right away:

```
private void addBtn(ActionEvent event) {
        Test o = new Test();
        o.setTitle(title.getText());
        o.setCount(Integer.parseInt(count.getText()));
        mainApp.getData().add(o);
}
```

In a second step I added an additional button to amend the highlighted count cell:

```
private void editBtn(ActionEvent event) {
        Test o = getSelection();
        o.setCount(Integer.parseInt(count.getText()));
        mainApp.getData().set(tablePosition, o);
}
```

If I click the button, the cell will update the value, but it's not visible in the table. If I click the button a second time it will update the table.

To check for which row is highlighted I use the following functions:

```
private final ListChangeListener<Test> selector = new ListChangeListener<Test>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Test> c) {
        setSelection();
    }
};


public Test getSelection() {
    if (testTable != null) {
        List<Test> table = testTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        if (table.size() == 1) {
            final Test selection = table.get(0);
            return selection;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void setSelection() {
    final Test o = getSelection();
    tablePosition = mainApp.getData().indexOf(o);

    if (o != null) {

        title.setText(o.getTitle());
        count.setText(o.getCount().toString());
    }
}
```

In the initialize method I add a listener to the observable list:

```
final ObservableList<Test> t1 = testTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
t1.addListener(selector);
```

My Test class:

```
public class Test {

    private final SimpleStringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(); 

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count.set(count);
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count.get();
    }
}
```

How can I make the Edit button to update the cell value right away?

Comment: Two clarifications: first, what are `Object.setCount()` and `Object.setTitle()`. These methods don't exist. Second, can't you just use `testTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()` to keep track of the selected item?

Comment: Hi James_D. Sorry I just figured I had replaced something I should not. "Object" is actually "Test". It's my model class. I've added parts of it to my question above. To your second comment, I had lots of problems to get the selection working, but with my code above this seems to work quite well. All I'm having problem with is with edit/update. If I highlight a row, edit the count cell and hit the edit button it will update the value, but won't show the updated value in the table, unless I click the button again.

Comment: Do you have property accessors (i.e. `public SimpleStringProperty titleProperty() {...}` and `public SimpleIntegerProperty countProperty() {...}` methods) in your `Test` class?

Comment: I have copied my Test class into my question. I have normal getter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `PropertyValueFactory` as the cell factory for your table columns, you need to provide property accessor methods in order that the table cell provided by the `PropertyValueFactory` can listen to those properties for changes.

One correct implementation of using the JavaFX Property model looks like

```
public class Test {
    private final IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "count", 0);
    private final StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "title", "");

    public final int getCount() {
        return count.get();
    }
    public final void setCount(int count) {
        this.count.set(count);
    }

    public IntegerProperty countProperty() {
        return count ;
    }

    public final String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }
    public final void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
    }

    public StringProperty titleProperty() {
        return title ;
    }
}
```

With that, the following method will then correctly update the selected row in the table:

```
private void editBtn(ActionEvent event) {
    Test o = testTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (o != null) {
        o.setCount(Integer.parseInt(count.getText()));
    }
}
```

If that doesn't fix the problem for you, I recommend you edit your question completely and provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I use the following for cell factory:  `titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Test, String>("title"));`  `countCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Test, Integer>("count"));`  I updated my Test class code as you suggested, but I am still a little confused how would then change my edit button method?!